# Django REST Client

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, rest-client

I have server. He return json in next format:

```
{
    "count": 6, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "court": "http://reg-corruption.herokuapp.com/api/court/2/", 
            "result": "result2", 
            "date_meeting": "2014-03-12T17:50:30Z"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "court": "http://reg-corruption.herokuapp.com/api/court/2/", 
            "result": "result22", 
            "date_meeting": "2014-03-13T17:50:46Z"
        },   ] }
```

I want to write client. In client I can copy models.py, but how I can use it to send request to server. Main problem: I have file models.py and it is work with sqlite database. Can I use this file to connect to REST server? And can I load links to foreign key automatically?
Or what I mast to read or use?

Answer (score 1):

You need neither the models.py nor DB to connect to the server. Once you have the REST API url, required headers and authentication details, you can just write a REST client in any language you are comfortable in and connect to the server.

I will put few examples:

- Python : [Rest-api-in-python](http://isbullsh.it/2012/06/Rest-api-in-python/)
- Python : [python-rest-client](https://code.google.com/p/python-rest-client/)
- Java : [java-restful-client](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-apache-httpclient-restful-client-examples)

From you tags I understand you are using DRF for the server. You can check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/ also, for inbuilt testing REST client library in DRF.